# find top right corner of rotated textfield

Tags: actionscript-3, matrix, transform

I am using the following to rotate a textfield from its top right corner, I would like to know the best way to find the point of the top right corner.

```
           var txt:TextField = new TextField();
            txt.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
            txt.htmlText = "Some text here>";


            mtx = txt.transform.matrix.clone();
            MatrixTransformer.rotateAroundInternalPoint(mtx, txt.width, 0, -45);
            txt.transform.matrix = mtx;
```

EDITED:

I just written this test code below in the flash IDE (omg that hurts...), obviously there is an embedded font called Arial in the library. I can't get the circle to correctly position on the top right of the textfield.

```
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.text.TextFieldAutoSize;
import flash.geom.Matrix;
import flash.display.Shape;
import fl.motion.MatrixTransformer;
import flash.geom.Point;
import flash.text.TextFormat;
import flash.text.Font;

Font.registerFont(Arial);

var angle:Number = -45

var txt:TextField = new TextField();
txt.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
txt.embedFonts = true;
txt.defaultTextFormat = new TextFormat("Arial", 20, 0x0000ff);
txt.text = "Here is some text";
txt.border = true;
txt.x = 100;
txt.y = 100;
addChild(txt);

var circle:Shape = new Shape();
circle.graphics.beginFill(0x00ff00);
circle.graphics.drawCircle(-5, -5, 10);
circle.graphics.endFill();
addChild(circle);

var mtx:Matrix = txt.transform.matrix.clone();
MatrixTransformer.rotateAroundInternalPoint(mtx, txt.width, 0, angle);
txt.transform.matrix = mtx;

// The top right after being turned -45°
var localPoint:Point = new Point( txt.width, txt.height );
var globalPosition:Point = txt.localToGlobal( localPoint );

circle.x = globalPosition.x;
circle.y = globalPosition.y;
```

Comment: You need to be more specific, do you need "the current location of what used to be the top right corner"? Are you always turning the box by -45° or do you need a general solution for any rotation?

Comment: Ok I apologise, I would like to always get the top right corner of the txt TextField regardless of what the rotation angle is, do I need to use trig for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean what was the top right before turning it:

```
// The field's original top right corner:
var localPoint:Point = new Point( txt.width, 0 );
var globalPosition:Point = txt.localToGlobal( localPoint );
```

If you mean, after having turned the field:

```
// The top right after being turned -45°
var localPoint:Point = new Point( txt.width, txt.height );
var globalPosition:Point = txt.localToGlobal( localPoint );
```

EDIT:

Ok, after seeing your test I experimented with a bunch of things and I think I found something that will work:

```
var angle:Number = -45
var txt:TextField = new TextField();
txt.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
txt.defaultTextFormat = new TextFormat("Arial", 20, 0x0000ff);
txt.text = "Here is some text";
txt.border = true;
txt.x = 100;
txt.y = 250;
stage.addChild(txt);

var local3d:Vector3D = new Vector3D( txt.width, txt.height );

var circle:Shape = new Shape();
circle.graphics.beginFill(0x00ff00);
circle.graphics.drawCircle(-5, -5, 10);
circle.graphics.endFill();
stage.addChild(circle);

var mtx:Matrix = txt.transform.matrix.clone();
mtx.rotate( -45 / 180 * Math.PI );
txt.transform.matrix = mtx;

var globalPosition:Point = txt.local3DToGlobal( local3d );

circle.x = globalPosition.x;
circle.y = globalPosition.y;
```

If I run this, I get a TextField, turned -45 degrees with a green ball stuck to what-used-to-be-the-bottom-right corner. I don't know your MatrixTransformer class, but it should be able to work with any matrix.

Try and copy&paste this code and fiddle around with it until you get the result you want.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this doesn't seem to do the job on the rotated version, seems to point to the bottom right of the bounding box not the top right corner of the rotated textfield

Comment: @Neil, are you sure the first snippet doesn't work? It should give you the global position of what-used-to-be-the-top-right no matter what the current rotation or position is. Are you sure you are using the actual textfield instance itself as the "txt" part of txt.localToGlobal and not a holder DisplayObject?

Comment: EyeSeeEm, I've added a test above, unless i'm missing something I can't get it to work.

Comment: @Neil I just edited my answer, try the new code. It seems to be extremely fragile, so copy it 1:1. For example, if you leave out the local3DtoGlobal line, the entire TextField disappears... <3 flash

Comment: hey great work dude, I found that just adjusting the values in the Vector3D I can target any part I want. Thanks for your perseverance.